# $(document).ready(function ()... working just one column in a table?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a table from which I draw data from the database and there is a delete button on each column in the table. When I click the button comes modal. My problem is that the modal comes only when I click on the first line. the other line is dysfunctional.

Table

```
 <tr>

       <td>".$row['ad_date']."</td>
       <td>".$row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name']."</td>
       <td>".$row['position']."</td>
       <td>".$row['company']."</td>
       <td>".$row['job_definition']."</td>
       <td>".$row['contact']."</td>
       <td>
        <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat' data-id='".$row['id']."' id='delete1'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</button>
                          </td>

                          </tr>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#delete1').click(function (event) {
        $('#delete').modal('show');


    });
});
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with `ready`. You can't duplicate ID's in a page, they are unique by definition. Change to a class selector for buttons and will work fine. `$('.delete').click...`

Comment: do you only have 1 record coming back from the db? if not, then you need to switch from using an id on multiple delete buttons and use a class instead

Comment: Thanks for help @jtylerm

Comment: Thanks for help @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '$ (document)', which means that any time it is clicked, it will work. Put '.delete' (classes can be repeated, id not) for each button to open the modal, where your id '#delete' will be your modal, the id of your modal. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
    $('#delete').modal('show'); 
})
```

Comment: I know you're a beginner, I am, we're in it. Towards to be rich! See you!

Comment: @B.Grgr, your question was a little difficult to understand, I understood the implementation already did something similar ... Be more specific in the next, the staff responds faster

Comment: Thank you.Sometimes I don't understand my problems because I like to make a product without learning everything. I will be better.